# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 in iBeacon with JSON parsing

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, android-service, ibeacon

I'm working on iBeacon app with JSON parsing. When i use the beacon and JSON parsing individual the app is working and if i combine the both it's not working and the app crashing following error

```
10-29 00:15:10.669: D/Response:(22444): > [{"name":"John","uuid":"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D","major_id":"67889","minor_id":"7032","notification":"Welcome","type":"Website","website":"estimote.com"}]
10-29 00:15:10.674: D/jsonObj_Response:(22444): > {"notification":"Welcome","uuid":"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D","type":"Website","website":"estimote.com","major_id":"67889","minor_id":"7032","name":"John"}
10-29 00:15:10.679: W/dalvikvm(22444): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42039700)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at com.estimote.examples.demos.NotifyDemoActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(NotifyDemoActivity.java:376)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at com.estimote.examples.demos.NotifyDemoActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(NotifyDemoActivity.java:1)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-29 00:15:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(22444):    ... 4 more
10-29 00:15:11.409: D/AbsListView(22444): onDetachedFromWindow
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444): Activity com.estimote.examples.demos.NotifyDemoActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42c1b628 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.estimote.examples.demos.NotifyDemoActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42c1b628 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:452)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at com.estimote.examples.demos.NotifyDemoActivity$GetContacts.onPreExecute(NotifyDemoActivity.java:317)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at com.estimote.examples.demos.NotifyDemoActivity.onCreate(NotifyDemoActivity.java:151)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
10-29 00:15:11.424: E/WindowManager(22444):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

iBeacon Activity:

```
public class NotifyDemoActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private static String url = "http://myserver.com/beacon/staging/jsonstring.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "uuid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_major_id = "major_id";
    private static final String TAG_minor_id = "minor_id";
    private static final String TAG_notification = "notification";
    private static final String TAG_type = "type";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";


    //TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_major_id, TAG_minor_id, TAG_notification, TAG_type

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    JSONObject jObject=null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notifi_demo);

 contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                    .getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                    .getText().toString();


        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();

notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);

     // Default values are 5s of scanning and 25s of waiting time to save CPU cycles.
    // In order for this demo to be more responsive and immediate we lower down those values.
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1), 0);

    beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new MonitoringListener() {
      @Override
      public void onEnteredRegion(final Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {
 @Override
      public void onExitedRegion(Region region) {
       // postNotification("Thanks for your visit");
          notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);

      }
    });
  }


  private ListView getListView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Async Method :

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NotifyDemoActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    //JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                     JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);




                      for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                         //   JSONArray innerArray = jarray.optJSONArray(i);

                           // jObject = innerArray.getJSONObject(0);

                          //  JSONObject jobj = jarray.optJSONObject(i);

                            jObject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Log.d("jsonObj_Response: ", "> " + jObject);




                           // JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                            //TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_major_id, TAG_minor_id, TAG_notification, TAG_type

                            String id = jObject.getString(TAG_ID);
                            String name = jObject.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            String email = jObject.getString(TAG_major_id);
                            String address = jObject.getString(TAG_minor_id);
                            String gender = jObject.getString(TAG_notification);

                            Log.d("jsonid_Response: ", "> " + id);

                            // tmp hashmap for single contact
                            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                            contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                            contact.put(TAG_major_id, email);
                            contact.put(TAG_minor_id, address);

                            // adding contact to contact list
                            contactList.add(contact);

                            Log.d("jsoncontactList_Response: ", "> " + contactList);

                         //   for (int j = 0; j < innerArray.length(); j++) {

                           //  }
                      } 







                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("myTag", e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    NotifyDemoActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_major_id,
                            TAG_minor_id }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

            setListAdapter(adapter);


        }

        private void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


    }
```

Comment: In particular, please indicate which line this is: `com.estimote.examples.demos.NotifyDemoActivity$GetContacts.doInBackground(NotifyDemoActivity.java:376)`, as that is where the error appears to be.

Comment: Share your code too.

Comment: Which line is 376? I also notice that you don't seem to have a declaration of `jObject`, so I wonder if the code posted is actually the code you are running. Your LogCat suggests one of the `jObject.getString` calls is in error, but they wouldn't give the error you are posting.

Comment: Line 376 is contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);...And i declared jobject see JSONObject jObject=null;

Comment: I see, I missed that. What does your debugger tell you when you put a breakpoint on line 376?

Comment: In debug what should i check? If i use breakpoint the green line indicate to lv.setonItemClickListener line

Comment: I think, the problem is in ListView..

Comment: @rajraj You have a NPE(Null Pointer Exception), check which one of your variables is null.

Comment: I got the answer. I didn't extend superclass as ListActivity..Now it's working